# InputMismatchException when reading data

Tags: java, exception, networking, server, client

I'm writing a memory matching game where the user enters coordinates trying to match tiles on a grid and I'm trying to send the coordinates back and forth between a client and server, For some reason I get a InputMismatchException on line 124 in the server file during the second iteration of the loop, where I read the integer coordinate from the client file, this doesn't make sense to me since the server file reads the coordinate fine without an exception being thrown during the first iteration and I also print the coordinate write after reading it the first time to show it. I'm unfamiliar with this exception and I'm not sure what to do.

Here's the server file

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemoryGame {

    static int[][] cards = new int[4][4];
    static boolean upDown[][] = new boolean[4][4];
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println("a");
             ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(8080);
             System.out.println("b");
             Socket s2 = s1.accept();
             System.out.println("c");
             Scanner sc=new Scanner(s2.getInputStream());
             System.out.println("d");
             PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s2.getOutputStream());
             //DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s2.getInputStream());
             //DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s2.getOutputStream());
             System.out.println("e");
             int initialAmount = 0;
             System.out.println("Connected");
             p.println("connected");
             //os.writeUTF("connected");
             //String accept = is.readUTF();
             String accept = sc.nextLine();
        //setup();
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                 upDown[i][a]=false;
             }
         }

         //randomize
         int num[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
         int[][] cards2 = new int[4][4];
         Random random = new Random();
         int temp, t;
         for (int j = 0; j <= 20; j++) {
             for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) { //Randomize the card order
                 t = random.nextInt(1000) % 15;
                 temp = num[x];
                 num[x] = num[t];
                 num[t] = temp;

             }
             t = 0;
             for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) // Cards receive Numbers
             {
                 for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
                     cards2[r][s] = num[t];
                     t = t + 1;
                 }
             }

         }
        cards = cards2;
         //shuffle
         int start[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
         int cards3[][] = new int[4][4];
         Random ran = new Random();
         int tmp, i;
         for (int s = 0; s <= 20; s++) {
             for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) //randomize the card placements
             {
                 i = ran.nextInt(100000) % 15;
                 tmp = start[x];
                 start[x] = start[i];
                 start[i] = tmp;
             }
         }
         i = 0;

         for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) // put values in cards here
         {
             for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                 cards3[r][c] = start[i];
                 i = i + 1;
             }
         }

        //game(upDown, cards); // calls the game
         int noDownCards = 16;
         while (noDownCards > 0) {
             //displayBoard(upDown, cards);
             //String connected = sc.nextLine();
             System.out.println("     1 2 3 4 ");
             System.out.println("---+---------");
             for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 4; i1++) {
                 System.out.print(" " + (i1 + 1) + " | ");
                 for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                     if (upDown[i1][a]) {
                         System.out.print(cards[i1][a]);
                         System.out.print(" ");
                     }
                     else
                         System.out.print("* ");
                 }
                 System.out.println();
             }
             System.out.println();
             String s = "Enter co-oridinate 1";
             p.println(s);
             //os.writeUTF(s);

             //int g1x = is.readInt();
             int g1x = sc.nextInt();
             System.out.println(g1x);
             p.println(s);
             //os.writeUTF(s);
             //int g1y = is.readInt();
             int g1y = sc.nextInt();
             System.out.println(g1x);
             System.out.println(g1y);


             System.out.println(cards[g1x][g1y]);
             //os.writeUTF(s);
             p.println(s);

             int g2x = sc.nextInt();

             p.println(s);
             int g2y = sc.nextInt();

             System.out.println(cards[g2x][g2y]);
             if (cards[g1x][g1y] == cards[g2x][g2y]) {
                 System.out.println("You found a match");
                 upDown[g1x][g1y] = true;
                 upDown[g2x][g2y] = true;
                 noDownCards -= 2;
             }
             //os.writeInt(noDownCards);
             p.println(noDownCards);
             //is.readUTF();
             sc.nextLine();
         }
         //displaying the grid
         System.out.println("     1 2 3 4 ");
         System.out.println("---+---------");
         for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 4; i1++) {
             System.out.print(" " + (i1 + 1) + " | ");
             for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                 if (upDown[i1][a]) {
                     System.out.print(cards[i1][a]);
                     System.out.print(" ");
                 }
                 else
                     System.out.print("* ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }
         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("You win");
        }

         catch(Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }      

    }


}
```

Here's the client file

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client
{
//Start the Game
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        try
        {
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8080);
        //scanner for accepting data from serve
       Scanner sScan = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //new printstream for passing values to server
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
        //DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        //DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
         //String str = is.readUTF();
         String str = sScan.nextLine();
         System.out.println(str);
         String connect = "Players are connected";
         p.println(connect);
        // os.writeUTF(connect);

        MemoryGame m = new MemoryGame();
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        int noDownCards = 16;
        while (noDownCards > 0) {

       // String accept = is.readUTF();
            String accept = sScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hello again");
        System.out.println("Enter co-oridinate 1");
        String g1 = scan.next();
        if(g1.length()<2||g1.length()>2)
        {
         System.out.println("Invalid length");

        }
        //int g1x = Integer.valueOf(g1.charAt(0))-1;
        int g1x = Integer.valueOf(g1.substring(0, 1))-1;
        int g1y = Integer.valueOf(g1.substring(1, 2))-1;

        System.out.println(g1x);
        System.out.println(g1y);

        System.out.println("Sending coordinate");
        p.println(g1x);
        //os.writeInt(g1x);

        //String accept2 = is.readUTF();
        String accept2 = sScan.nextLine();
        p.println(g1y);
        //os.writeInt(g1y);

        //String accept3 = is.readUTF();
        String accept3 = sScan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter co-oridinate 2");

        String g2 = scan.next();
        if(g2.length()<2||g2.length()>2)
        {

         System.out.println("Invalid length");

        }
        int g2x = Integer.valueOf(g2.substring(0, 1))-1;
        int g2y = Integer.valueOf(g2.substring(1, 2))-1;

        p.println(g2x);
        //os.write(g2x);

        //String accept4 = is.readUTF();
        String accept4 = sScan.nextLine();
        p.println(g2y);
        //os.write(g2y);

        //noDownCards = is.readInt();
        noDownCards = sScan.nextInt();
        //os.writeUTF(str);
        p.println(str);
        }
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should use BufferedInputSteram instead